# lsof select only socket opened by an user

Tags: lsof

I can get the socket in listen state opened by an user with this code

```
lsof -sTCP:LISTEN -n -i -P |awk '$3 == "user" { print $0 }'
```

I would like to now if there is an option to lsof that also filter by user (or by process name by the way). I know that lsof has the -u option but this:

```
lsof -sTCP:LISTEN -n -i -P -u username
```

List all the files opened by user username, it doesn't filter the network connections (and it's slow).

Answer (score 2):

> Normally list options that are specifically stated are ORed

Try this instead:

```
lsof -u username -a -i -sTCP:LISTEN -nP
```